# SSH tunneling shows no response.

Tags: networking, tunneling

I am trying to ssh tunnel into this CTF box and this is the command I am using

```
ssh -L 2020:127.0.0.1:5901 user@196.168.88.47
```

and to connect to the 2020 socket I use

```
ssh -p 2020 root@127.0.0.1
```

when I do that, it gives me no prompt. Just blank lines no response nothing. BTW `5901` is an open port on the CTF machine.

I already have a shell on the machine, I tried

```
netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED 
tcp4 0 0 localhost.5801 localhost.30508 ESTABLISHED
```

so the connection to the port has been established. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could be connecting to the wrong service, as port 5901/tcp is commonly used for VNC, not SSH.

You can use `nmap` to identify the correct service. After starting the tunnel:

```
nmap -sV -p 2020 localhost
```

It will show you the service and version active on that port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that your own local firewall isn't blocking the connection to localhost:

```
iptables -t filter -L -n
```